# Android's webview doesn't show google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, webview

If i start this application, i can see the webview correctly, but it doesn't load google maps (https://maps.google.com/maps?q=43.0054446,-87.9678884&t=m&z=7), but it loads the normal google page (https://www.google.it/#q=43.0054446%2C-87.9678884). Why? Is there a way to fix it?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    {
         WebView myWebView;
         String mapPath = "https://maps.google.com/maps";

         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
         {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
             myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
             String map2="?q=43.0054446,-87.9678884&t=m&z=7";
             myWebView.loadUrl(mapPath+map2);    
         }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Now i have another problem. This is my xml Layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_height="@string/hello_world"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to display the WebView in the upper half of the screen, but when the link is loaded, the page is fullscreen (even if i insert something else under the webview). Why?

Comment: I think you need to fix the WebViewSettings. For example, you will definitely need `myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: I had just to remove the S from the httpS. Now i have another problem. I updated my question,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just removed the S from the httpS and it works. I don't know if this can help.

Answer (score 3):

For me I was missing the `myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`.

This is my code:

```
//set the webview and have open the map
mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mywebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

mywebview.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
mywebview.loadUrl(mapPath+map2);
```

Thanks to the commenter adding that, I was going a little nuts.